# Create repeating tuple type in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, elasticsearch, tuples

I have an API (the elasticsearch bulk API) that accepts an array of operations, which are basically pairs where the first element is object specifying the operation (index, update, create, delete) and the second is the data (not in the case of delete).

A single operation could be typed as (simplified):

```
type BulkUpdate = [{ update: { _index: string, _id: string } }, { doc: object }];
type BulkIndex = [{ index: { _index: string, _id?: string } }, object];
type BulkDelete = [{ delete: { _index: string, _id: string } }];
type BulkOperation = BulkUpdate | BulkIndex | BulkDelete;
```

The entire parameter is then a flattened array of the above tuples - a list of operations and optionally data.

How do I model this type in Typescript? It's not a tuple as it has indeterminate length, and it's not an array as element types depend on their index (eg, with the exception of BulkDelete, the even indices contain the "operation" and the odds ones the "operand").

Answer (score 1):

The strongly typed, NodeJS package [`@elastic/elasticsearch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/elasticsearch) declares the `bulk` actions like so:

> `type Action = IndexAction | CreateAction | UpdateAction | DeleteAction`

where `IndexAction` is

```
interface IndexAction {
  index: {
    _index: string
    [key: string]: any
  }
}
```

and so on.

[Check the source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/7b21f92cebd6047345d01d8b83ceab0eb180bd41/lib/Helpers.d.ts#L80) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks, but that models the individual "tuples" that make up parameter (like the types I created above), but it doesn't answer how to type a variable length array made up of one or more of those tuples.

Comment: Can you clarify that further? What'd be the JSON that you're trying to specify the types for?

Comment: The JSON would be (for example):
[
  {update:{...},{doc: {...}},
  {index:{...},{...},
  ...
]
IE, the concatenation of a variable number of TS tuples